# Does the Android 2.2 Image class have the ability to render .gif files?

Tags: android-imageview

Nothing fancy, NO ANIMATION, simple .gif images.

I know there is support in SDK later versions but would like to use my target device as a minimum 2.2

Many thanks.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it is discouraged: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables-from-images